# Python Web scrape stock charts, code stuck when stock symbol not found

Tags: python, loops, redirect, web-scraping

I have a list of stock symbols to run through this website and then wish to get the links of the stock charts

However, When there is an error with a symbol, the website redirects to another page and python stops running the remaining symbols

my symbol list is : WOW, AAR, TPM

the error happens at AAR

Can anyone please give some guidance to this Py noob?

```py
from urllib import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

newsymbolslist = ['WOW','AAR','TPM']

i=0

try:
    while i < len(newsymbolslist):
        try:
            html = urlopen( 'http://bigcharts.marketwatch.com/quickchart/quickchart.asp?symb=AU%3A'+newsymbolslist[i])
            bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
            images = bs.find_all('img', {'src': re.compile('market')})
            for image in images:
                print (image['src'] + '\n')
                i += 1
        except:
            print "error"
            i += 1
except:
    pass
```

The best result is that it gets all the link for stock charts, can tell me which stock symbol encountered an error and continues to run the remaining symbols

Thank You

Comment: Where is the link to the chart defined? Could you post a sample output please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no exception thrown when the symbol doesn't exist. This means that `i` doesn't get incremented since it is inside the for loop iterating over the images found (Just an empty list in AAR case). The result is that `i` never fufills the condition to break the while loop and it continues forever. Moving the `i+=1` into a finally block ensures it is always incremented.

```
from urllib import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
newsymbolslist = ['WOW','AAR','TPM']
i=0
try:
    while i < len(newsymbolslist):
        try:
            html = urlopen( 'http://bigcharts.marketwatch.com/quickchart/quickchart.asp?symb=AU%3A'+newsymbolslist[i])
            bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
            images = bs.find_all('img', {'src': re.compile('market')})
            for image in images:
                print (image['src'] + '\n')      
        except Exception as e:
            print "error"
        finally:
            i += 1
except:
    pass
```

As an improvement you could remove the while loop entirely by just iterating over the symbol list you have. Then you don't need to worry about incrementing `i`:

```
for symbol in newsymbolslist:
    try:
        html = urlopen( 'http://bigcharts.marketwatch.com/quickchart/quickchart.asp?symb=AU%3A'+symbol)
        bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
        images = bs.find_all('img', {'src': re.compile('market')})
        for image in images:
            print (image['src'] + '\n')      
    except Exception as e:
        print "error"
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a logic error. Here is a change I think will get you unstuck.

```
from urllib import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

newsymbolslist = ['WOW','AAR','TPM']

i=0

try:
    while i < len(newsymbolslist):
        try:
            html = urlopen( 'http://bigcharts.marketwatch.com/quickchart/quickchart.asp?symb=AU%3A'+newsymbolslist[i])
            bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
            images = bs.find_all('img', {'src': re.compile('market')})
            for image in images:
                print (image['src'] + '\n')
            i += 1
        except:
            print "error"
            i += 1
except:
    pass
```

This is probably a bit simpler:

```
from urllib import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

newsymbolslist = ['WOW','AAR','TPM']

try:
    for symbol in newsymbolslist:
        try:
            html = urlopen( 'http://bigcharts.marketwatch.com/quickchart/quickchart.asp?symb=AU%3A'+symbol)
            bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
            images = bs.find_all('img', {'src': re.compile('market')})
            for image in images:
                print (image['src'] + '\n')
        except:
            print "error"
except:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly more concise and re-using existing connection:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

newSymbolsList = ['WOW','AAR','TPM']

with requests.Session() as s:
    for symbol in newSymbolsList:
        try:
            html = s.get('http://bigcharts.marketwatch.com/quickchart/quickchart.asp?symb=AU%3A'+ symbol).content
            bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
            images = [img['src'] for img in bs.select('img[src*=market]')]
            print(images)
        except Exception as e:
            print("error", e)
```